# IPhone SDK Application Loader - Error Occured Talking to Itunes Store

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I've had no problems creating and submitting apps previously (roughly 7 months ago or so) and now that I just recently created one and tried to upload it, it says:

> Application Loader is currently Unavailable.
>
> We're having trouble connections to the itunes store. please try again
>   later.
>
> An error occurred talking to the iTunes Store

I haven't touched iphone sdk during that span. I did update everything to the latest upon using it again. I thought it was just a server error but this has been on for a week already.

Some speculate it's a Java problem - updated it, didn't work.

Some think it's an iphone sdk, xcode, iOS version - updated, didn't work.

Comment: You should accept the previous answers to your questions or you might not get as many replies. :)

Comment: what do you mean? I rarely go to stack overflow so if I'm missing something here, let me know

Comment: if you don't accept any answers, the people who took the time to answer you don't stand to benefit from answering you. when you do accept an answer they will receive points. and points make stackoverflow go round.